# While making post call i am getting below exception

Tags: java, apache

Error description:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.HttpHost.getAddress()Ljava/net/InetAddress;
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:102)
```

Could anyone help me here....what i am missing ???

Comment: What version of the library are you using? `getAddress()` was introduced in 4.3.

Comment: Could also be a jar conflict. Open the dependency tree and analyze.

Comment: I m using these jars ------->  httpclient-4.3.6.jar
httpcore-4.4.jar

Answer (score 0):

use below sample code :

// HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

```
    String url = "https://selfsolve.apple.com/wcResults.do";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=& num=12345";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}
```

}